# How to extract Metadata from any stream (other than Shoutcast or Icystream )?

Tags: stream, http-headers, metadata, fetch, shoutcast

Can anyone please explain how extraction for different streams really works? I get the part about Icy-meta (Shoutcast) but how to get the meta data from non-shoutcasr or non-Icy injected streams.
Amarok, rhythmbox, vlc they all seem to get it right. no matter what stream you play they'd fetch right meta data so can someone help me explaining technicality behind meta fetching from live stream or what to look for. You can be technical, don't worry I'll get it :)
Thanks in advance.
[image: This is the picture of amarok fetching meta]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic solution.  Every container format has its own metadata format.  VLC and such have demuxers for many.  You could just hand it off to FFmpeg/FFprobe and let it figure it out, but realistically if you want to implement this in your application, you'll have to demux that particular format anyway.